# What does 'ask for' mean in this case?

Tags: vocabulary

> He stopped a passing guard, but didn't dare mention platform nine and
>   three-quarters. The guard had never heard of Hogwarts and when Harry
>   couldn't even tell him what part of the country it was in, he started
>   to get annoyed, as though Harry was being stupid on purpose. Getting
>   desperate, Harry **asked for** the train that left at eleven o'clock,
>   but the guard said there wasn't one. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

In this context, I guess, ‘asked for’ seems to mean ‘asked about’ the train. But I’ve not found the usage yet. Would you let me know what the phrase exactly means in this case?

Answer (score 6):

"asked for" differs slightly from "asked about".

"asked for" is a request not so much for information about the train, but is more a request for directions to it. Example: "He asked for the exit."

"asked about", while similar, could be used by someone out of idle curiousity who has no need of actually getting on the train. Indeed, "asked about" could refer to a request for information about the type of locomotive or number of carriages or what colour the paintwork is.

Answer (score 5):

In that case, *asked for* means "asked for information about"; you could rephrase the sentence as follows:

> Harry asked for information about the train that left at eleven o'clock, but the guard said there wasn't one.

This is what the [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/ask) says:

> **ask for something** to ask for a job/a drink/an explanation
>
> > I am writing to ask for some information about courses.

One of the definitions given from the NOAD for *ask* is the following one.

> request (someone) to do or give something:
>
> > Mary **asked** her father **for** money.
> >
> > Don't be afraid to **ask for** advice.

Comment: Would you let me see any dictionary that says like your words?

Comment: so, all your cases just mean "request/demand something: request an explanation, demand money, request advice. But "request/demand the train"? Isn't it awkward?

Comment: "Ask for the train that left at eleven o'clock" means "request someone to give information about the train that left at eleven o'clock"; it doesn't mean "request someone to give the train that left at eleven o'clock."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a US/UK thing, or maybe it is just poorly worded. I think the more common phrasing would be, "... asked about the train ..." or "... asked for information regarding the train ..."

Normally, to "ask for" something means to request that it be given to you or done for you. Taken out of context, I would understand "Harry asked for the train" to mean "Harry requested that someone give him a train". You can ask for something that isn't physical, like "ask for information" or "ask for more time", but it's the same idea: You want someone to give you information or you want someone to give you more time.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you ask for a train it means you want to buy a ticket for that train. If he didn't want a ticket he should have "asked about" the train.